# Reading escaped unicode sequence from a text file in Node.JS do not render on console or api response

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-escapes

**What I tried**

```
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs')
const app = require('express')();

let data = fs.readFileSync('./unichar.txt')
let str = "\u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)"
console.log("from file ========> ",data.toString('utf-8'))
console.log("from str variable >>>>>>>>>> ", str)

let buffer = new Buffer(data,'utf-8')
console.log("After some encoding changes ++++++++> ", buffer.toString('utf8'))

app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.contentType('text/plain')
    res.write(data)
    res.write(str)
    res.end()
    next()
})

app.listen(3002)
```

**Output**

```
// from console
$ node index.js 
from file ========>  \u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)

from str variable >>>>>>>>>>  女裝多way連身裙(長袖)
After some encoding changes ++++++++>  \u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)

// from postman
\u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)
女裝多way連身裙(長袖)

// from curl
$ curl localhost:3002
\u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)
女裝多way連身裙(長袖)
```

**Problem**
I have a problem with unicode text rendering.

For example please consider I have a file with the following single line of unicode characters - `\u5973\u88DD\u591Away\u9023\u8EAB\u88D9(\u9577\u8896)`

When I read the file using `fs` module and display the contents it is not rendered as actual characters. It is just displayed as unicode sequences.

Where as when I manually load the same string into a variable and then console that variable, then the actual japanese characters are rendered on the console.

The same problem happens when the same data is send as http response.

**Why is the text from file do not get rendered as actual Japanese characters?**

I 'am confused and not sure what is to be done to get the file contents display/rendered as actual Japanese characters on console and http response.

It would be very helpful if somebody could please help me to figure out the missing part?

Thankyou

Comment: You cannot use the `\uxxxx` notation in text files. Is the first character in your file perhaps a backslash?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen The text file I mentioned here is for simplicity and it begins with `\u5973` But the actual file is a csv beginning with alphabets.

Comment: A text file with `\u5973` in it contains six US-ASCII characters, not one Japanese Unicode character, as you seem to assume.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks. So you mean I have to manually parse them individually manually programmatically?

Comment: Your unicode file `./unichar.txt` does not actually contain Japanese characters. How was it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems based on a misunderstanding: The `\uxxxx` notation cannot be used in text files. In other words: A text file with

```
\u5973
```

in it contains six US-ASCII characters, not one Japanese Unicode character.

The `\uxxxx` notation works only in Javascript, where the statement

```js
fs.writeFileSync("./unichar.txt", "\u5973");
```

produces a text file with

```
女
```

in it.